# CSS - Auto-height div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some expanding content in my `#main` (or) `#panel` (got this from a template) div, but when you expand it, it pops to the unknown, under the page...

How could I make my `main` div expand with my content.

### CSS

```
#main
{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I also have some JS/Ajax scripts that expand the page to the right size when you switch page, could they affect...?

See live demo **[here](http://artotek.fi)**! (The (i) button)
The divs expand when you click on them.

A few times it worked on another computer, but very randomly..

Tell me if you need the scripts or more code.
Basically, everything's wrapped in .main -> .panel

**Simple: When the div is expanded, expand the main div's height to fit it.**

```
.panel
{
    position: relative;
    display: table-cell;
    width:100px; 
    vertical-align:middle; 
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some more code- or preferably a jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @ExtPro http://jsfiddle.net/9zUNS/ I'd need the div n.1 to be expanded by default. My ajax page load function get's confused if you try to resize the page when it's already loaded, but it works if you open the div, switch tab and come back.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with the main div, but the class panel.

```
.panel {
padding: 3.5em 2.5em 3.5em 2.5em;
position: absolute; // I'm the problem
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 45em;
}
```

This is also a problem.

```
#me .pic img {
position: relative; // I'm evil
display: block;
height: 100%;
}
```

My debugging may have been awry though, since it doesn't want to play nice and stick with what I want it to do sometimes.

Let me know if this helps in some way, and if you need help debugging anything from there.

***EDIT***

Your problem may just be a matter of recalling the Script that you use to re-size the main div when the script that displays the hidden divs content goes off. That should re-size the page to fit the new content.

I can't locate where this script goes off, so if you can provide it, I could figure it out.

Comment: Well now how could I fix this?

Comment: You removed the overflow as suggested by Mike. Put the overflow back, because it is not the issue.

Comment: I actually figured it  out. The page load function detects the page height On Load. However if you expand the div, the function is like 'Whaat..', however if you leave the div open, switch page and come back the function is like ''Oh there's some content, let's expand''.

Comment: So I'd need the first div to be expanded by default. Script here: http://jsfiddle.net/9zUNS/

Comment: If you wanted to make that div expanded by default:

Make sure this span looks like this <span id="infoactive" class="active">Lue Artotekistä</span>

And <div class="infoexpanderContent" style="cursor: default; color: inherit;"> does not have 'display: none;' attached to it.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is actually "how do I make my main div's height change dependent on it's contents" then all you need to do is remove `overflow: hidden;` from the css class.